# Minimizing expression over symmetric matrices

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following maximization problem over space of symmetric matrices A and positive definite H

$$R=\max_{A\in S(R^d)}\frac{\text{tr}(HA)^2+2\text{tr}(HAHA)}{\text{tr}(AHA)}$$

So far I've used regular `Maximize` over matrix coefficients, but it only works for small matrices. Is there a way to massage this problem into some other optimization tool that's more matrix specific?

````
Clear[a];

d = 2;
A = Array[a[Min[#1, #2], Max[#1, #2]] &, {d, d}];
vars = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[A]];
H = DiagonalMatrix[{1., 2.}];
objective = (Tr[H.A]^2 + 2 Tr[H.A.H.A])/Tr[A.H.A];
Maximize[objective, vars] // First (* 6.56155 *)
```
````

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's an eigenvalue problem! How to see that? Well, let's define some example data:

```
d = 3;
H = N@DiagonalMatrix[Range[d]];
A = # + #\[Transpose] &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
```

Both numerator and denominator can be written as bilinear forms of the vector $\operatorname{vec}(A)$:

```
Avec = Flatten[A];
```

To this end, we need the following matrices and vectors:

```
Hvec = Flatten[H];
(*representing multiplication by H from the left*)

HL = KroneckerProduct[H, IdentityMatrix[d]];
(*representing multiplication by H from the right*)

HR = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[d], Transpose[H]];
(*representing the bilinear form of the numerator*)

M1 = 2 HR.HL + KroneckerProduct[Hvec, Hvec];
(*representing the bilinear form of the denominator*)
M2 = HL;
```

Testing for correctness:

```
Avec.M1.Avec == Tr[A.H]^2 + 2 Tr[H.A.H.A]
Avec.M2.Avec == Tr[A.H.A]
```

> True
>
> True

Thus your optimatization problem is equivalent to maximizing a Rayleigh quotient:

$$
\max_{A \in S(\mathbb{R}^d)} \frac{\operatorname{vec}(A)^\top \, M_1 \, \operatorname{vec}(A)}{\operatorname{vec}(A)^\top \, M_2 \, \operatorname{vec}(A)}
$$

Pulling back the bilinear forms `M1` and `M2` to the subspace of symmetric matrices is fairly easy:

```
idx = Partition[Range[d^2], d];
p = DeleteCases[Flatten[UpperTriangularize[idx]], 0];
q = DeleteCases[Flatten[UpperTriangularize[Transpose[idx]]], 0];
L = SparseArray[
   Transpose[{Join[p, q], 
      Join[Range[Length[p]], Range[Length[p]]]}] -> 1.,
   {d^2, Length[p]}, 0.
   ];
B1 = L\[Transpose].M1.L;
B2 = L\[Transpose].M2.L;
```

Test:

```
Avec[[p]].B1.Avec[[p]] == Avec.M1.Avec
Avec[[p]].B2.Avec[[p]] == Avec.M2.Avec
```

So we arrive at the following maximization problem

$$
\max_{v \in \mathbb{R}^{d (d+1)/2)}} \frac{v^\top \, B_1 \, v}{v^\top \, B_2 \, v}
$$

and this an generalized eigenproblem for the matrix pair $(B_1,B_2)$. In fact, we are looking for the greatest generalized eigenvalue and that can be obtain as follows:

```
Eigenvalues[{B1, B2}, 1]
```

> 30.0574

However, this method has super high numerical complexity. The matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$ are of size $n \times n$ where $n = \frac{d (d+1)}{2}$. And most generalized eigenvalue algorithms require to invert $B_2$ (or to solve linear system with it by utilizing a $LU$-factorization). This takes $O(n^3)$ time, so the overall complexity is $O(d^6)$. However, if $H$ is diagonal, then $B_2$ is also diagonal and the inversion of $B_1$ has complexity only $O(n) = O(d^2)$.

I think one can bring it down to $O(d^3)$ for generic symmetric positive-definite $H$ by diagonalizing $H$ first (before building $B_1$ and $B_2$. In fact, I believe that one can arrange everything so that $B_2$ is the identity matrix; then we would have reduced the problem to a classical eigenvalue problem for a single matrix $B$. And that can be solved very efficiently with the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration), requiring only matrix-vector multiplications with $B$. And since $B$ has quite a particular structure (a rank one matrix + `HR.HL`), there is quite a lot of potential to make this faster.

Comment: For computing the eigenvalues of a symmetric-definite pencil, you indeed can convert it into the usual symmetric eigenproblem by performing the Cholesky decomposition of `B2`; as it is diagonal in this case, one can just do `With[{dd = DiagonalMatrix[1/Sqrt[Diagonal[B2]]]}, Eigenvalues[dd.B1.dd, 1]]`. (The general procedure is described [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02165306), or see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9844) for some *Mathematica* code.)

Comment: Thanks for in-depth answer! Actually the problem is rotationally invariant and H is covariance matrix so I can always replace H with a diagonal

Comment: You're welcome! And as J.M. mentioned, one can indeed use a Cholesky-factorization of `H` to recast everything into a classical eigenvalue problem. And since only the highest eigenvalue is required, the power method should work fine. The first paper cited by J.M. might be really worth a read.

Comment: Could you please explain how  to go from M1 and M2 to  B1 and B2?  I am not familiar with the syntaxes you wrote.  What transformation did you use?

Comment: The matrix `L` has dimensions `{9,6}`. It represents a linear embedding of an $\mathbb{R}^6$ into the $9$-dimensional space of $3  \times 3$ matrices. More detailed, it maps `{1,0,0,0,0,0}` to the matrix `{{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}} `or rather its flattened version `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}`; `{0,1,0,0,0,0}` to `{{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,0}}`; `{0,0,1,0,0,0}` to `{{0,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,0,0}}`; `{0,0,0,1,0,0}` to `{{0,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}`; `{0,0,0,0,1,0}` to `{{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0}}`; and `{0,0,0,0,0,1}` to `{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,1}}`.

Comment: After all, it is just important that the columns of `L` form a basis for the space of symmetric matrices.